# Is it possible to fetch record count for dynamodb scan result without pagination?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, phalcon

I have a set of records in my dynamodb table. I would like to fetch the number of records based on a certain criteria **without pagination**. 
Here is my code for fetching the data:

```
$db = $this->getDi()->get('dynamodb');
$dynamodb = $db->createDynamoDb();
$FilterExpression='tenant_id = :tid';
$ExpressionAttributeValuesArr=array(':tid'=>array('S'=>'16008d5bXYZ'), ':mod'=>array('S'=>"leads"));
scan_request=array(
                    'TableName' => 'xxxx',
                    'Count'     => true,
                    'FilterExpression' => $FilterExpression.' AND #module = :mod',
                    'ExpressionAttributeNames' => array('#module' => 'module'),
                    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $ExpressionAttributeValuesArr,
                );
$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan($scan_request);
```

This code returns a list of records and the count but not the whole set or the whole count as I can see the `LastEvaluatedKey` field returned in the response. I need to have the count for the whole record set returned for this scan. How can I do this ? Is this even possible without paginating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, `COUNT` is a late request- that is, dynamo *reads* (and **charges** you for doing so) every record in the table, before applying the filter and then reducing that to the count.

Which is why you have to paginate, because the count operator will only "see" up to the page length.

If you do not need to do this programatically/accurately, I would point you towards the "estimated count" that AWS show in the DynamoDB console.